# Passing constants as arguments in INNO's Exec()

Tags: windows-services, arguments, exec, inno-setup

I have created an installer using Inno Setup in which I am executing an exe that I created to create a small service inside Windows XP. I need to pass two arguments to the exe - "-install" and the path of the installation directory. I have no way of expanding the constant {app} to pass the actual value inside of {app}. Is there some way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what you want, but maybe you are seeking the [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_expandconstant.htm) function?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of ExpandConstant but even that does not allow me to pass the installation path as an argument. If I do this

Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\Depends\myEXe.exe'), '-install "ExpandConstant('{app}')"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

it wont put the {app} path as the argument. Instead, it will put ExpandConstant({app}) as the argument. Is there a way of getting around this is my question.

I hope this is clearer

Comment: @Rishi: Of course it does. `ExpandConstant` is a part of the string literal!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\MyApp.exe; Parameters: "-install {app}";
```

I've done it before using InnoSetup and it puts the correct value for {app}.

If you are still having problems, please post your code.

Comment: True. For now, I am using [Run] instead of the Exec function inside [Code]. I was just wondering if someone knew how to use Exec function to run the exe and pass the app path as an argument

Comment: In that case, something like this should work:
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\MyApp.exe'), '-install "' + ExpandConstant('{app}') + '"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);